# Com Smoketurner dropwizard-swagger with dropwizard 1.1.4 throws Null Pointer Exception at specFilter class

Tags: spring, java-8, dropwizard, swagger-2.0

I am trying to upgrade DropWizard version from `0.9.2` to `1.1.4`, and in turn change the  `com.smoketurner dropwizard-swagger 1.1.1-1` which downloads dependencies:

```
io\swagger\swagger-jersey2-jaxrs\1.5.15\swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.15.jar
io\swagger\swagger-jaxrs\1.5.15\swagger-jaxrs-1.5.15.jar
io\swagger\swagger-core\1.5.15\swagger-core-1.5.15.jar
io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.15\swagger-models-1.5.15.jar
io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.15\swagger-annotations-1.5.15.jar
```

My application uses Spring framework for operations. On Hitting the swagger screen it shows 500 error with following exception -

```
27-Sep-2017 14:16:31:514 | ERROR | dw-50 - GET /swagger.json | i.d.j.e.LoggingExceptionMapper | Error handling a request: 94c37d34407485e8
    ! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    ! at io.swagger.core.filter.SpecFilter.filter(SpecFilter.java:47)
    ! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.BaseApiListingResource.process(BaseApiListingResource.java:130)
    ! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.BaseApiListingResource.getListingJsonResponse(BaseApiListingResource.java:167)
    ! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.getListing(ApiListingResource.java:33)
    ! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    ! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
```

Sample dropwizard-swagger application works absolutely fine, however when integrated in my application does not show up. The endpoints when tried through Postman  etc. work fine.

Please help.

Comment: how do you configure swagger in dropwizard and on which line of your code does the stacktrace come from?

Comment: module dropwizard-swagger from com.smoketurner configures the swagger. Resources registered using @Api annotation. While generating swagger.json, I get this exception from class io.swagger.SpecFilter  filter method when it tries to get all the registered paths.

Comment: Could you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this to be reproduced.

Comment: Will work on getting it.

Comment: Issue  resolved.  Maven repository cleaned, and project cleaned up and started from scratch. It seems, there was a conflict between the old and new dropwizard-swagger versions for fetching related dependencies.

Comment: Cool :) Shall close this post then.

Comment: This also seems to be an issue if you don't specify an @Api annotation on top of your resource class. Adding this annotation immediately fixed the SpecFilter NPE for me.

Answer (score 4):

This issue happens when drop wizard swagger tries to find your resources but could not find it, it is either you specified a wrong resource package in you server configuration yaml file or you do not have a resource package at all and thus it could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar stacktrace because of different reason, and Google brought me to this question.
If you're getting NPE in SpecFilter, check if your resource class is annotated with "@Api"